# Raspbian Jessie: Cannot mount NTFS external harddrive anymore after 'apt-get upgrade' (fuse device is missing)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, fuse, ntfs-3g

After I used apt-get upgrade earlier today, my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie) stopped being able to automount my external harddrives anymore. Automounting worked perfectly fine before apt-get upgrade, but now I can't even manually mount my external HDDs anymore.

This is the error message I received:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt 
>   modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.26-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
>   ntfs-3g-mount: fuse device is missing, try 'modprobe fuse' as root

'modprobe fuse' gives me the same error message:

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.26-v7+/modules.dep.bin'

I reinstalled the kernel and bootloader using this command:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`

But this did not help.

From reading other forum posts, it may look like my kernel and fuse might not be compatible - but how would that have happened? I feel I'm a bit out of my depth here.

Some forum posts suggested a restart will help, but this didn't solve the issue for me.

Alternatively, I also found a [post from drownboat on Reddit from two years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/36vl42/cant_modprobe_fuse_in_debian/) that looks promising - but to be honest, I have no idea if this is just another red herring or if this is indeed the problem I'm facing. In any case, I'm not sure what exactly/how drownboat did it:

> I suspect that what is happening is that updates to the kernel and
>   grub config are being written to the /boot folder, but not onto the
>   boot device. This has caused the modules and the kernel to go out of
>   sync. [...]
>
> I fixed it by adding /boot back to /etc/fstab, rebooting to another kernel where the modules were still working, thus mounting /boot, and finally reinstalling apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Some more info:

```
uname -a
```

> Linux raspberrypi 4.4.26-v7+ #915 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:08:44 BST 2016
>   armv7l GNU/Linux

```
dpkg -s fuse
```

> Status: install ok installed 
>   Priority: optional
>   Section: utils
>   Installed-Size: 103
>   Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) 
>   Architecture: armhf
>   Version: 2.9.3-15+deb8u2
>   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libfuse2 (= 2.9.3-15+deb8u2), adduser, mount (>= 2.19.1), sed (>= 4), udev | makedev
>   Conffiles:
>    /etc/fuse.conf 298587592c8444196833f317def414f2
>   Description: Filesystem in Userspace
>    Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) is a simple interface for userspace programs to
>    export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel. It also aims to provide a
>    secure method for non privileged users to create and mount their own filesystem
>    implementations.
>   Homepage: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION (see further below for details)!** It turned out that the boot partition was not mounted and the operating system reverted to the old kernel before the apt-get upgrade. So I just had to make sure that /boot was automounted at startup so the correct kernel was used.

**Further steps in my error analysis ():**

OK so I managed to fix the issue myself. It really just turned out that the /boot partition was not mounted and thus my Raspberry Pi reverted to the old kernel instead of the fancy new one that came with apt-get upgrade.

I found the problem by using `uname -r`, which gave me '**4.9.35-v7+**' as an answer. This was strange because the original error message had a different version number:

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could
>   not open moddep file '/lib/modules/**4.4.26-v7+**/modules.dep.bin'

(My emphasis)

When I navigated to /lib/modules using `cd /lib/modules` I also saw this:

> pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules $ ls
>   4.9.35+  4.9.35-v7+

So the error message about a fuse device missing really seemed to have something to do with a mismatch of kernel and fuse versions. The discrepancy between version numbers led me to believe that the wrong kernel was being used (like drownboat also stated in their Reddit post two years ago).

**This is how I fixed the problem (SOLUTION):**

`sudo nano /etc/fstab/`

Then I added the following lines to fstab:

> # automount /boot partition at startup 
>   /dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot vfat defaults 0 2

After rebooting, I used `sudo raspi-config` to check if the boot partition was mounted properly (raspi-config will only let you enter its menu if the partition is mounted, otherwise it will tell you that you need to mount the boot partition first).

Then I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` again to doubly ensure that the latest kernel was installed on the boot partition too - but I don't know if this was a crucial step.

Finally, after another restart, I was able to mount/automount my external harddrives again.

Hope this helps anyone else out there having the same issue as me! :)

Comment: Excellent - thanks for coming back and updating with the solution.

In my case I didn't understand the auto mount part, and don't have a /dev/mmcblk0p6, however, you were right that the module versions were different to the kernel version.  The --reinstall step is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you!! I had to replace the SD card, and I ended up downloading latest Stretch image, and used it to boot with HDD (after replacing the fstab and command line), I was having similar problem including few disabled USB peripherals. Once I saw your post I used `sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` and all is well since..

Comment: Using OMV on buster.  Like @obrienk, the `--reinstall` / `reboot` worked for me.  Life-saver, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, the solution is pretty simple.
I run `apt update` and `apt upgrade -y` and then `apt install ntfs-3g`, after these, I try to mount the disk and met this error.
The solution is just `reboot`
After reboot,  try to mount again, and thing worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to get Open Media Vault working. There were missing or unmatched kernel files, outdated libraries etc.  I ran the updates in the link below and got it working.

Update system's package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

upgrade all installed packages to their latest versions:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to mount a FAT32 USB on Buster Lite with

```
pmount /dev/disk/by-label/<my-usb-label>
```

The messages implied the system was trying to mount an ntfs device. 'NTFS signature missing' etc.

Before trying anything clever, I tried @Kenneth's suggestion of a reboot. It fixed the problem.

Worrying to see Linux behaving like Windows 8-{

Answer (score 0):

Crash after kernel upgrading
apt-get update & dist-upgrade

impossible to mount ntfs usb disk

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.87-v7+
ntfs-3g-mount: fuse device is missing, try 'modprobe fuse' as root
```

Thanks a lot  for this workaround :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33629254)